# Oracle Apex 5: how do I remove spaces between rows and inside cells

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Oracle Apex 5 classic report, **How to remove extra space between rows and margins and padding between cells** because the report is just too big.

Is there a property value I need to change? Is there a CSS for this? In which property/attribute to put the CSS if there is? I am using universal theme 42, and the standard template for the report.

Comment: I was trying to use interactive reports and I can't use interactive reports because I have a join query with no distinct column key. This was tested on another interactive report and it still didn't work. I'm mainly concerned with classic report because it allows me to create report based on query with join table with needing to have an index key
this code worked on interactive query
.a-IRR-table td {
    padding: 0px;
}

Answer (score 1):

CSS tuning is very easy in APEX (if you know where to tune). You can change an appearance of the report in two ways (or with a combination of these ways):

1. Go to `Shared Components` -> `User Interface` -> `Templates`, find there a template that you need (by default, APEX uses the template with name `Standard`), create a copy. In the region template's properties, you will find how APEX defines divs, the table, rows, cells, etc. You can change any part of a template or create your own. After that, go to the page, open `Report Attributes` and choose the new template.
2. Open page attributes:

[image]

choose `CSS` tab. You can overwrite a standard APEX CSS class here. As I understand, you know, how CSS works.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for your explanation but I can't find exactly what you mentioned.